Serving images from a hidden folder in a normal html page
I have a page index.php
<?php
echo "some text";
?>

I want to serve the image from a hidden folder with the src attribute set to "/hidden/image.jpg".
I have seen and tested various methods to achieve this, and I can get the image to display. However, I need to set the headers to image/.jpg which prevents the text from being displayed properly.

It's not clear... Please provide other details, useful to get an aswer. In your snippet there is no attempt to serve an image
